# Is there a way to call a function when a column header is clicked in Primefaces DataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So right now if you want to sort a data table you can give the column a sortBy attribute and when you click the header it will sort by whatever that attribute is.

Is there a way in which I can call my own custom function instead when you click the header?

Comment: There's some ambiguity in your question. The word "function" is in Java web development world usually interpreted as a JavaScript function since there's no such thing as a "function" in Java. But starters often confuse Java methods with "functions". Also you didn't mention/tag anything about JavaScript in your question. So, what do you really want? Do you want to invoke a JavaScript function or a Java (JSF) method?

Comment: @BalusC Good point, the question is not that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a handler to all of the column headers of a data table with the following script.

```
jQuery('th').children().bind('click', function(evt) {
  alert(evt);
  //Insert logic to determine which header was clicked and do stuff
});
```